# Puppeteer: Changing Screenshot Format with 'Type' Option Doesn't Update File Extension (.png to .jpeg or .webp)?

Tags: puppeteer

The screenshots file got `.png` extension when type changed to `jpeg` or `webp`

I want the screenshots to be in different format than `png`.
I have used the `type` option and the screenshots are written in different format but the extension of screenshot file is still `.png`

```js
const image = await page.screenshot( { type: "webp", fullPage: true });
```

Comment: How are you using the `image` variable after this? If you're manipulating the file in memory, there's no concept of "extension". If you want to write to disk, use `path` and provide your desired extension there.

Comment: Thanks for that comment it made me think. It looks like the problem is in the `jest-image-snapshot` lib which supports only png :/